# Unable to append data into existing hive table with HiveContext

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, hivecontext

We are reading data from a `hive` table with `hiveContext` using a `spark dataframe`. After doing some aggregations on the data we store this data into another table (which already has data). But the new data is not being appended to the existing table... and not showing any error either...

Note: Before storing into `hive` I am able to print the `dataframe`.

Comment: Please add relevant information. How are you writing the data to the table? How is the table structured? And other related information that might help the answerers. Also, read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: post the code and errors/exceptions which you are using and getting. No one be able to help without that information. They can be so many reasons by theory

Comment: grammatical fixes.

Comment: Thanks for your replay... the was issue resolved...

Answer (score 0):

```
df.write.insertInto(target_db.target_table,overwrite = False)
```